# Ubuntu installation problem in remaining free space

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I'm using windows 10 but I left some free space of about 300 GB so that I can install Ubuntu 14.04 on it , but windows is not showing any partition and I cannot get any further in installation , I also don't want to lose my data in windows so kindly guide me about this problem that how can I install Ubuntu easily in the free space I left.

Comment: To insure that you don't lose your data due to unexpected consequence, you should **always** have a backup.

Comment: If you didn't create a partition, then why would you expect to see one?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see a partition in Windows because you did not create one - it is unallocated space.
Download an Ubuntu installation image and burn the ISO file to a DVD or create an USB media.
To create the USB media in Windows - open **command prompt as administrator** and execute :

```
diskpart
list disk  
select disk *  
clean  
create partition primary  
active  
format fs=fat32 (quick)  
assign letter=**  
exit
```

Note : `*` = number of the USB drive | `**` = select a free drive letter

Mount the Ubuntu ISO file and copy everything to your USB drive.

Open **command prompt as administrator** again and execute :

```
powercfg /h off
```

Then open Windows Control Panel (the old version - not the modern design).
Select **Energy Settings** - enable **show hidden settings** - **uncheck Fast Boot**.

After having done this - shutdown the machine completely - do NOT reboot !

Start the computer and select the UEFI Ubuntu USB drive option to boot from.
Select **Try Ubuntu without installing** and wait until the Live desktop appears.
Click **Install Ubuntu** on the desktop and when asked, choose **Something else**.

Install Ubuntu to the unallocated (free) space that you created in Windows before.
After installation has finished, boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu as default system.

Answer (score 0):

Simply boot from the live CD/USB to Ubuntu and you can select to install it to the free space or select "something else" at the partitioning and create your own partition settings.
Dont forget to create an EFI partition, a root and a swap partition (if you want to play it safe I recommend to install /home on a separate partition as well). If you have issues with the dual boot just boot back from the live usb and can fix it with boot-repair (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

After the installation:

Windows can't see your Linux partition cause it is with a different, unsupported by Microsoft filesystem like ext4 or btrfs or xfs etc.
What I did before to see and access my stuff on the Linux partition from Windows is that I created a schema (or not sure how you call it in vbox for sure) of the Linux part of the hdd with Virtualbox and was able to boot that in a virtual machine accessing live to the Linux OS on the hdd.

The other option which can be easier is to give Linux a smaller space on the disk and share the stprage where you put your files with Windows on an NTFS partition.

Hope this helps you planning your partition config.

Br,
A